# how do I increase the number of parameters in this javascript?

Tags: javascript, textarea, radio-button

Declaration: I am not sure if that is a parameter. Please enlighten.

I have a medical questionnaire form with almost 19 yes and no radio buttons.Each question's radio buttons must have a unique input name in order to make it work. I manage to find a suitable code to toggle an text area if the yes radio button is selected however, it can only work in one of the input name and there are 18 more which needs it to be working as well.

My main question is:

```
function displayTextBox()
    {
        var objElement = document.getElementById('addmed');
        addmed.style.display = 'block';
        addmed.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }

    function hideTextBox()
    {
        var objElement = document.getElementById('addmed');
        addmed.style.display = 'none';
        addmed.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

    function validate()
    {
        var arrElements = document.getElementsByName('medq');
        var objElement;
        var boolContinue = false;
        var objaddmedtext;

        for(var i=0, _length=arrElements.length; i<_length; i++)
        {
            objElement = arrElements[i];

            if(objElement.checked)
            {
                if(objElement.id == 'yes')
                {
                    objaddmedtext = document.getElementById('addmedtext');

                    if(strTrim(objaddmedtext.value).length>0)
                    {
                        boolContinue = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    boolContinue = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if(boolContinue)
        {
            alert('Continue, user completed the information.')
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Ask user to complete the data.')
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes all white space characters from the string.
     * 
     * @param: {String} String to trim.
     * 
     * @return {String} Trimed string.
    */
    function strTrim(strTrim) 
    {
        return strTrim.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    }
```

Looking at this javascript,a textarea

```
<div id="addmed" style="display:none;visibility:hidden; margin-left:10px; width:110px;">
        <textarea id="addmedtext" cols="60" rows="6" placeholder="Please give details with dates"></textarea>
</div>
```

will only appear if the yes radio button is selected for

```
<tr>
<td width="33">1.</td>
<td width="491">Heart or circulatory problems including: high blood pressure, heart attack, angina, heart murmur, heart failure, palpitations, circulatory problemseg. whitefinger, blocked arteries, stroke aneurysm.</td>
<td width="68"><input name="medq" id="yes" type="radio" value="yes" onclick="displayTextBox()"/><label for="yes"> Yes </label></td>
<td width="78"><input name="medq" id="no" type="radio" value="no" onclick="hideTextBox()"/><label for="no"> No </label></td>
```

However, this is only 1 question...I have 18 more question with `name="medq 1 to 18 "`.

Any ideas how to edit the javascript to add the parameters??

Comment: Sort of a side comment: If you are doing a *medical* questionnaire where people's health could be affected, I would strongly urge you to perform extremely stringent testing to ensure that your code is correct (i.e. make a unit test for *each* question yes AND no, in case for example a question happens to always be marked yes or always be marked no due to a bug).

Comment: First off, a "yes and no radio button" is called a checkbox. That's what those are for. Second, you need to get the inline sizing and style data out of your HTML. I would also recommend using a library providing some sort of selector, such as (but not limited to) jQuery, for getting and hiding messages. Finally, if you don't use a selector, make sure getElementById is available.

Comment: can someone explain what does `f.style.display = 'block';
    f.style.visibility = 'visible';` means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to have unique ID on every radio button. But you need the same NAME on each pair of YES/NO button to process the selected one of the pair. So you can have

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" id="foo_y" value="yes" /><label for="foo_y">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="foo" id="foo_n" value="no" /><label for="foo_y">Yes</label>
<textarea id="foo_text" name="foo_text"><textarea>
```

Now, for the "yes" radio buttons, you can add onclick="displayTextBox( this )". "this" is a pointer to the current radio button.

You can then update the function like so:

```
function displayTextBox( f ) { // f is the field that was clicked
    f.style.display = 'block';
    f.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Now it's a generic function. Do the same for the "hide" function.

Finally, you can update your validate function to loop over the array of form input fields instead of looking at the one field.

1. `var arrElements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");`.
2. Inside your loop: `if( (objElement.type === "radio") && (objElement.checked) ) {`.
3. Don't use `if(objElement.id == 'yes')`, check for the value of the current field: `if(objElement.value == 'yes')`
4. Finally, you can grab the text from the related textarea: `objTextArea = document.getElementByName( objElement.name + "_text" );`

So, you're just making each of the existing functions generic and looking for the meta data of each field, rather than trying to code for each field.

Comment: hi...sorry just want to understand what do you mean by field that was click?? u mean the value?

Comment: for the field to be click do you mean the 19 fields?

Comment: after implementing the changes...i realise that if for question 1 i click no, for qns 2 i click yes the text field come out and if qns 3 i click no the text field will hide again...any idea how make it such as if at least 1 is yes then text box remain there?

Comment: Does each pair of radio buttons have an associated textarea? That's how I read it. If there's only one textarea for all of the radio buttons, then if any one "yes" radio button is selected, the single textarea displays?

Comment: hmm only 1 text area if any of the question have an answer yes...thank you so much...great help seriously...

Comment: oh yah but what is f? do i need to replace f? because i see some other javascript coding they use e which i guess stands for element...

Comment: Traditionally, "e" means "event", as in a click or a change. Here, "f" represents the actual DOM object that is the clicked INPUT field. This keeps you from having to specifically reference a particular field by ID or NAME.

Comment: Oh yah i rouhly got the idea already...but i realise when i change the answer from yes to no the text area wont disappear back. 
do i need to remove the `onclick="hideTextBox()"` from my original code?

Comment: No, you just need to update hideTextBox(). Maybe "if no radio pairs are marked 'yes' then hide the textarea."

Comment: sorry i am not very sure of how to write the if statement for javascript but i wonder if `if (objElement.value=='yes' >1){` is added to hide function is it right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9653/discussion-between-hubert-and-iknowkungfoo)